# How can I write $A\sin⁡(w_1t−k_1x) + B\sin(w_2t− k_2x)$ as$ 1$ trigonometric function?

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to do a problem and I need the frequency of the combined sine functions.

I am looking for the right trigonometric formula to do this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Are $x,y$ each functions of a single variable like $t$ ? Otherwise it's a two variable function.

Comment: Assuming $w_1,w_2, k_1,k_2,A,B$ are constants and $x,t$ are independent variables, if the expression is equal to $C\sin F$ or to $C\cos F$ where $C$ is constant and  where $F$ is linear in $t$, then  by partially differentiating twice by $t$ we see that the ratio of $\sin (w_t-k_1x)$ to $\sin (w_2t-k_2x)$ must be constant  unless $w_1^2=w_2^2.$

Comment: Waves combined with different frequencies  and phase shifts do not in general result in harmonic motion.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let use [**Arbitrary phase shift**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Arbitrary_phase_shift) formula

$$a\sin x+b\sin(x+\theta)= c \sin(x+\varphi)$$

where

- $c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + 2ab\cos \theta}$

and

- $\varphi = \operatorname{atan2} \left( b\,\sin\theta, a + b\cos\theta
     \right)$

Comment: This doesn't look like one trigonometric function (though I doubt it's possible). I would note that.

Comment: @AndrewLi    $ c \sin(x+\varphi)$ is not a trigonometric function?

Comment: But $c$ includes $\cos$ and $\varphi$ includes $\text{atan2}, \sin, \cos$?

Comment: I already tried it but it isn't of much help. I get t and x, which are variables, in the frequency. It has a constant frequency according to my instructor which is in terms of w1 and w2 and k1 and k2.